# How to query through more than 2 million documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have more than 2 million documents in my mongodb atlas collection. I am using Mongoose to read/write data into the cloud collection but as the size is too huge, queries like `Model.find()` takes infinite time, unless I use `.limit(x)` with it.

Is there any way or concept I should look for this?
I just want to analyse the documents for some simple queries and then put the data to use in React frontend.

Comment: We would need more information like the specific queries you are working with, your current indices to better understand your situation.

Comment: These are all basic queries like Find all documents containing country as : Australia, which will be done using Model.find query, but as the documents are more than 2 mil, it is taking too much time. So any way of getting this through?

Comment: Did you index the common fields involved in the queries? like country as you given example

Comment: Nope, Acutally I am not familiar with indexing. Can you please help me regarding that?

Comment: Can you update your question with those common/most frequent queries you used? We will need a concrete example of your queries to see how we can help. Or you may also want to check out this [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/) on indexing strategies as a starter.